# Converting a multi Nexus file into multiple nexus files

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a Nexus file that contains 447 genes, but I need 447 individual Nexus files (one for each gene) does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: I tried using bioPython, however only one alignment per file is supported.

Comment: What have done so far?

Comment: I haven't actually written anything yet because I'm not sure how to go about it. There are 37 taxa so I thought I could maybe split the file every 37 lines, but I don't know enough about nexus file formats to know how to actually write new nexus files.

Comment: Atleast give the  sample input data

Answer (score 0):

If by genes you mean sequences, then I can give you a proposition. You can save nexus file as a fasta file and then you can read every sequence and save it to fasta file (which is better for saving sequences). Here is code

```
import os
from Bio.Nexus.Nexus import Nexus
from Bio import SeqIO

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Read the nexus file
    with open('test.nexus', 'r') as fh:
        N = Nexus()
        N.read(fh)
        N.export_fasta('seqs.fasta') # Export to temp .fasta file

    # Read all sequences
    seqs = [record for record in SeqIO.parse('seqs.fasta', 'fasta')]
    # Write every seq to "sequence_name".fasta file
    for seq in seqs:
        SeqIO.write(seq, handle = f'{seq.name}.fasta', format = 'fasta')
    # Remove unnecessary temp file.
    os.remove('seqs.fasta')
```

Results are fasta files with single sequences in it.